Visual Studio Code Server (CLI) Local without tunnel
I want to host the vscode server on one of my servers using code CLI Local, but without using code tunnel, which connects to a GitHub/Microsoft account.
My goal is to connect to this instance using desktop vscode and my company's own VPN tunnel without having a third party in between.
I'm hopeful that there might be a solution to this. Is this possible?
